# Python to run a specific flask program until hitting another button

Tags: python, flask

I have a sweep function that returns a string of data. What I want to do is have two buttons, a start button and a stop button. When the start button is hit, the sweep function is called, and once that function is finished it is called again and again and again. Running nonstop until the stop button is hit. I'm using flask.

I don't think this is a duplicate because most of the other question regarding this want it to stop at a specific time, ie. run for 45 seconds. I need mine to run continuously until the stop button is pressed.

My thought process was to do something like

```
@app.route('continue_sweep', methods=["GET","POST")
def continue_sweep():
    while (sweep_continue flag = true):
        sweep()
```

and then in my stop button function just have a sort of break all? I don't know if that's a thing or not, but that was my thought process.

```
@app.route('stop_sweep', methods=["GET","POST"])
def stop_sweep():
    break all -->> end the above sweep function here
```

--------------------Updated code
I can do something like this

```
@app.route('/start_continue_sweep', methods=["GET","POST"])
def start_continue_sweep():
    if init_tester_flag == False:
        initialize_tester()
    stop_btn_flag = False
    while (stop_btn_flag == False):
        sweep_continue_fun()
    return render_template('sweep_results.html', sweep_str = remove_err_str)

def sweep_continue_fun():
    sweep_btn()
    return render_template('sweep_results.html', sweep_str = remove_err_str)
```

and it gives me what I want, but does not update the sweep_results.html. Is this why I would need something like what was mentioned in your answers below? Or is there an easier fix to make it update?

Comment: It can be done in either frontend by `javascript` or in backend by `streaming contents`. But both take your time to learn. If you just need pieces of codes that works: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is the explanation and sample code of Javascript setInterval. [Here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/) is the documentation and examples of how to do `Steaming Contents` in Flask by `yield`.

Comment: Would this still be the same if I was just going to call the function again? Meaning that once the sweep function finished running, just call it again? Would that be an option?

Comment: yes, that's how `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in javascript works. Request should always comes from user end. And you may also want to learn `I/O` and `Event-driven programming`.

Comment: I updated my code. Is that why I would need to do something along those lines?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to build, but html didn't update is because what @TimRoberts mentioned: one request -> one response, then it's done. You might find out the `sweep_continue_fun()` will continuously running before returning response, that is because it is a `long time task` and html haven't been returned yet.

Comment: If you're trying to make a simple UI for python functions, try [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). Flask is a webserver framework. I can only help you here and you might need to learn more related knowledge before going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how web requests work. One request gets one response, then it's done. If you want something to move continuously, you will have to do that with Javascript in the browser, not in the server.

Comment: How would I go about that in javascript? Are you able to direct me where to look at all?

Comment: If you haven't done Javascript before, then you have a learning curve to climb.  Most Javascript frameworks, like https://jquery.com, have tools to help with animation.  Raw Javascript uses `setInterval` to request a periodic callback of a function.

Comment: The only thing I've done in Javascript so far is written a TFC, which had no interaction with the front end. Thanks for the link. I appreciate it

Comment: would it be the same if all I was doing was calling the function again. Meaning that, once the function finished just call it again until that button is hit?

Comment: That still has to come from the browser.  Once you have returned a response, the server's connection to the browser is disconnected.  Nothing happens until there is a new request.

Comment: I updated my code. Is that why I would need to do something along those lines?

Comment: No.  YOU CAN'T DO THIS FROM THE SERVER.  Remember, your browser is sitting and waiting for a response from you with the wheel spinning.  It can't display ANYTHING until you return a rendered template, and then the exchange is over until the browser asks for something else.

Comment: Okay thank you, I appreciate pointing me in the right direction